# PDE changing Boundary Conditions

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am having difficulty grasping how it is that you can have 2 different boundary conditions that give the same solution to the PDE. I am hoping that I could possible see an example where this is the case.

Update: The pde that I have is $(u_x)+(u_y)=0$
with BC : $u(x,0)=\sin(x)$

Comment: Which PDE? There are a few.

Comment: Hi Daniel, sorry I have just updated my question with the relevant PDE

Comment: So do you want a different boundary condition that will give you the same solution?

Comment: Ya, Daniel thats what Im trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible when the boundary condition is given over a characteristic curve. In your example the characteristic curves are $x-y=C$ and he BC is given on $y=0$, so that in this case there is a unique solution $u(x,y)=\sin(x-y)$.

Consider now the same equation with BC $u(x,x)=0$. Then $u(x,y)=\phi(x-y)$ is a solution for any differentiable function $\phi$ such that $\phi(0)=0$.